# How fix Azure web app deploy error with VSCode?

Tags: deployment, azure-web-app-service

I followed quickstart-nodejs guide.
Difference is region. guide region is 'eu', my region is 'kor'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode

Error came when after zipping.

오후 3:46:22: Error: request to https://mpexpressapp011.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true&author=VS%20Code failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

Why and How?

Please help me. (ㅠㅠ)

[image]

Comment: What is the region you have selected Korea Central or Korea South ?

Comment: I have followed the document and able to deploy the application and able to acces the application successfully. Could you please share the screen shot of the error

Comment: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQpbZ.png)Check the deployed App Image

Comment: ***Error came when after zipping.*** Where is the step of zip in the given document ?

Comment: ECONNRESET error means that your connection is being killed by the server or by some gateway/firewall that is intercepting tcp communication. Check if your connection can reach the target host.

Comment: Check your network once, try to connect to another network and cross check

Comment: @NedCrow - Any Update regarding THE ISSUE ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. My App location is 'Central US'. I am trying to deploy my NodeJS service. It was working few hours back and I was able to deploy it but just stopped working now.

Comment: I solved it by downgrading the VSCode version. (1.66 -> 1.64.2)
Thank you everyone! We are the world!

Comment: You can get the older versions from this link https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65

Comment: I had the same issue, fixed by switching to code-insiders (https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) instead of downgrading.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Exactly the same issue since yesterday, Brazil South region. Stopped working out of the blue.

EDIT: After rolling back Visual Studio Code update to february, it works again. Looks like the update from VScode broke something

Comment: Rolling back to February (version 1.65.2) fixed it.

Comment: Issue reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146470

Answer (score 3):

After rolling back Visual Studio Code update to february, it works again. Looks like the update from VScode broke something.

Aye!!! It worked here too!

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced that same problem, but I follow the Alberto Recommendation and worked perfectly here, I did downgrade from 1.66 to 1.65.2.

Comment: Providing more info on the procedure and a link could help the OP solve the issue faster.

Comment: Same issue. Running 1.66.0. It worked last week. According to Windows 10, 1.66.0 was installed on 3/30/22. Has anyone filed a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me too, deploying in UK SOuth. Rolled back to January (1.64.2 to be safe) and worked perfecty. So I would agree, some new issue in the March release (1.66.0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The situation was the same in Japan.
After hours of trying various things, I was able to find and solve it.
I don't know who put it in, but the crime of taking a lot of time from developers around the world is very heavy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Same in NZ.  New laptop upgrade to V1.66 and would not work.  Uninstalled and installed V1.65 and the upload worked.  Interestinglky the size of the sipped filed was 1Mb smalled with the 1.66 version (1.66 size of zipped file was 58.3 Mb and 1.65 and below size of zipped file is 59.4 Mb)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also encountered the same issue in INDIA. downgrading the application to Jan Version: 1.64.2 (Universal) resolved the issue.

I am using a Macbook air (M1 chip)

You can download other versions from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65)

Answer (score 1):

It worked after reverting to previous version